# Find a certain member in this XML with Python (Etree)

Tags: python, xml

Morning All,
I have been searching every where and I am realizing I might not be using the right search terms. Basically, I have the snippet of code below, and I want to print the name value of entry name and whether it could find member value of 'Trust' (true or false output would be great).

```
    <entry name="Stuff">
    <to>
        <member>1</member>
        <member>2</member>
        <member>3</member>
        <member>Trust</member>
    </to>
</entry>
<entry name="Stuff2">
    <to>
        <member>1</member>
        <member>2</member>
        <member>3</member>
        </to>
</entry>
```

I know I can access the member name values in my list with:

```
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='configs/Stuff.xml')

for each in tree.iterfind():
    print each.get('name')
    print each.find('to').find('member').text
```

How would I either print all of the values (Entry Name, Value 1, Value2, etc), or true/false if it exists (Entry Name, True)? I find a lot of half way answers but I cannot seem to find my specific issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate this in a function.

```
for each in tree.iter():
    print each.tag
    if each.text == "Trust":
        return True
return False
```

Comment: Would I need 2 for loops? One for each "entry" and one for each "member" perhaps?

Comment: I don't believe so(I think it iterates through all members in a tree), but you can only have one root tag per xml parse.  To expedite it you might want to navigate down the tree before it gets to the loop using:

    new_tree = tree.find("to")

Answer (score 0):

This was the code that ended up doing what I needed, the code I used above was sample code, and I am modifying this answer to attempt to solve the answer, but if anyone else is trying to do similar this should point you in the right direction.

```
for each in tree.iterfind('entry'):
for all in each.find('from').findall('member'):
    print each.get('name')+';'+all.text
```

This prints the name and member for each member I could now write this out or filter as needed. Good luck all.